# Passing whole object vs Passing Primitive value -

Tags: java, interface, service

Is there a overhead or performance issue in passing whole object vs passing
primitive value as in option 1 and 2?.

[ EDIT: I meant to say passing a reference of a Java object vs primitive type. From 
@T.J. Crowder, I understand that there is no performance issue here as the object reference size is same in both cases. But interms of API design style / perspective, which 
option is the best one? ]

I am at present defining the service layer. I prefer "Type 1" as I like it, 
but if 'Type 2' is good for performance, I will go with Type 2.

```
Class A {
    User user = SomeClass.getUser("anUser");

    B b = new B();

    b.doSomeOperation(user);  // option 1
    b.doSomeOperation(user.getUserId()); // option 2
}

Class B {

    // Type 1
    public void  doSomeOperation(User user){

        // some work done by using user.getUserId()
        // I do not really need whole user object now.
    }

    // Type 2
    public void  doSomeOperation(int userId){
        // some work done by userId
    }
}
```

Comment: it don't really pass the object.it just copies the reference to that object,which points to the real object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You never pass a "whole object" in Java. What gets passed is a reference, which is about the size of an `int` or so. So what you pass — an object reference or an `int` ID — has no effect on the performance in terms of the call to the function itself.

However, passing the object reference means you can act directly on the object, whereas passing the ID means that if you need to access the object, you need to look it up again by ID, which could have a negative performance impact.

---

**Edit**: Based on your update:

> I understand that there is no performance issue here as the object reference size is same in both cases. But interms of API design style / perspective, which option is the best one?

That totally changes the question (and seems to drop the "performance" part of it entirely).

It totally depends on A) What you're going to do in `doSomeOperation`, and B) What information the *callers* of `doSomeOperation` are most likely to have.

If `doSomeOperation` is going to need more than just the user ID, then of course pass in the object.

If `doSomeOperation` doesn't need anything else other than the user ID, then you probably want to just pass in the ID. There are trade-offs. If you pass in just an `int` ID, on the one hand `doSomeOperation` loses its coupling to `User` (which is usually good); on the other hand, `doSomeOperation`'s argument becomes largely meaningless. (An `int` could be anything; but `User` has meaning.)

If `doSomeOperation` takes a `User` argument but really only needs the user ID, you're placing a burden on callers of `doSomeOperation`: If they just have the ID, they have to go look up the object solely for the purposes of passing it into `doSomeOperation` (which is then going to ignore everything but the ID). That's clearly bad from a performance perspective.

So I think the summary is: If `doSomeOperation` requires anything of `User` beyond just its ID, pass in `User`. If it only needs the ID and doesn't need anything else from `User`, just pass in the ID.

Answer (score 1):

- if you are sure that you *won't* need any other info than just user id then go for `type 2` otherwise 1.
- more over you aren't passing whole object , just reference's bits will be copied.
- suppose you want to update some information in `doSomeOperation` of user then you will have to fetch that object using ID that will be costly.

Answer (score 1):

From the performance point of view, there is no significant difference between `type1` and `type2`. From the design point of view there is.

> As a general rule, pass only what is
>   needed, nothing more and nothing less.

If you pass a reference to the `User` object your `doSomeOperation` will be coupled to `User` class. This might present you with problems in the future, such as difficulty in unit testing the method etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the instance of the user object pass that.  When you pass the object you are only passing a ref not a chunck of memory.  If you pass the id you will have to retrieve the user probably from the database.  that is overhead.